# choose variable via input (python)

Tags: python, variables, input, types

i wanna choose the variable via an input

```
a=1
b=2
c=3

x=input("a/b/c")
```

The Idea is now that the calculation is 7 times 1 and therefore the solution: 7

```
solution=7*a

print(solution)
```

But python recognizes the input as string not as a variable. How do i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn a string into a variable like this.

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

x = input("a/b/c: ")
x = locals()[x]

solution = 7 * x
print(solution)
```

Comment: Good answer. It would be clearer, though, if you don't use the same variable for the string and for the retrieved value.

Comment: @alexis The original value is not used afterwards, so there is no reason to keep it around and use two names for essentially the same value. I believe shadowing the original is appropriate in this case.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, and I have done similar myself on occasion. But here it's more likely to be confusing/misleading to the OP and other readers with this problem (i.e., relative beginners).

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a 'lookup table' that will map the chars to numbers.

```
lookup = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
x=input("a/b/c: ")
value = lookup.get(x)
if value is None:
    print('invalid input')
else:
    print(f'Solution is {7 * value}')
```